# jQuery - if element = (class) then variable = (variable)

Tags: jquery

I have a simple function that I want to run 3 times.  Instead of using the same function I'd like to create some sort of IF statement that says if banner = banner class, then variable = relevant variable.

I'm just not sure how to word my if's.

Any help would be great!

```
var $banner1 = 'Some Text',
    $banner2 = 'Some More Text',
    $banner3 = 'Even More Text',
    $someText;

    if ($('.banner-01')) {
        var $someText = $banner1;
    }

    if ($('.banner-02')) {
        var $someText = $banner2;
    }

    if ($('.banner-03')) {
        var $someText = $banner3;
    }

$('.banner-01 .info').each(function(){
    $(this).html($someText);

});

$('.banner-02 .info').each(function(){
    $(this).html($someText);
});

$('.banner-03 .info').each(function(){
    $(this).html($someText);
});
```

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't make much sense - can you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to do? What is the intended relationship between `$banner1` (which is just a string variable) and `$('.banner-01')`, which is a jQuery method that will fetch an array of all elements with the `.banner-01` class?

Comment: @AntP - Sorry - So IF the banner has the class of .banner-01 then var $someText = $banner1; and so on for 2 & 3.  It's essentially so the banners use the same function but the variable changes depending on what banner it is.  I'm just not sure how to write the if statement correctly.

Comment: `$('.banner-01')` will always be a truly object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `if` statements at all.

What you want is to iterate over each element with each class and set the text to the appropriate variable.

`$('.banner-01')` gets you an array of all elements with the "banner-01" class. You can then use `each` to perform an action for each of these, like so:

```
var $banner1 = 'Some Text',
    $banner2 = 'Some More Text',
    $banner3 = 'Even More Text',
    $someText;

$('.banner-01').each(function () {
    $(this).html($banner1);
});

$('.banner-02').each(function () {
    $(this).html($banner2);
});

$('.banner-03').each(function () {
    $(this).html($banner3);
});
```

Then, you fire your one method once, not once *per element*.

At the minute, `$someText` will always end up as `'Even More Text'` (because `$('.banner-03')` will always return a value and therefore the condition will evaluate to `true`). Once `$someText` has been set 3 times and reached its final value, you then go through all of the elements of every class and set them all to `'Even More Text'`.

Following your code through to illustrate the problem:

```
var $banner1 = 'Some Text',
    $banner2 = 'Some More Text',
    $banner3 = 'Even More Text',
    $someText;

if ($('.banner-01')) {
    // 1. Sets $someText to 'Some Text'
    var $someText = $banner1;
}

if ($('.banner-02')) {
    // 2. Sets $someText to 'Some More Text'
    var $someText = $banner2;
}

if ($('.banner-03')) {
    // 3. Sets $someText to 'Even More Text'
    var $someText = $banner3;
}

// From this point on, $someText is 'Even More Text'.

$('.banner-01 .info').each(function(){
    // 4. Sets elements with banner-01 class to 'Even More Text'
    $(this).html($someText);

});

$('.banner-02 .info').each(function(){
    // 5. Sets elements with banner-02 class to 'Even More Text'
    $(this).html($someText);
});

$('.banner-03 .info').each(function(){
    // 6. Sets elements with banner-03 class to 'Even More Text'
    $(this).html($someText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding what you're trying to do, I think this will work:

```
var $banner1 = 'Some Text',
$banner2 = 'Some More Text',
$banner3 = 'Even More Text',

if ($('.banner-01')) {
    $('.banner-01 .info').each(function(){
        $(this).html($banner1);
    });
}

if ($('.banner-02')) {
    $('.banner-02 .info').each(function(){
        $(this).html($banner2);
    });
}

if ($('.banner-03')) {
    $('.banner-03 .info').each(function(){
        $(this).html($banner3);
    });
}
```

And actually you don't even need the if statements because if the elements are not found you'll have an empty array and the `each` function will just be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the code below. This would add the advantage that it would work regardless of the number of banners you have.

```
var banners = ["Some Text", "Some More Text", "Even More Text"]; // Store banner text in an array.
for(var counter = 0; counter < banners.length; counter++) {
    var sel = ".banner-"; // Set selector prefix
    if(counter < 10) sel += "0"; // Add 0 if less than 10
    sel += counter + " .info"; // Add suffix
    $(sel).html(banners[counter]); // Set banner html
}
```